# Using NavigationDrawerController with ToolbarController in the same UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, material-design, cosmicmind

In [CosmicMind / Material](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material) library, they are showing how to use one module at a time like:

```
window = UIWindow(frame: Device.bounds)
window!.rootViewController = AppToolbarController(rootViewController: RootViewController())
window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

what if I want to add another module to the same `rootViewController` like:

*ToolbarController* with *NavigationDrawerController* ?

I'm new to iOS and Swift, I would be thankful for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the idea behind the navigation controllers, like `NavigationDrawerController` and `ToolbarController` is that you can stack them. So if you want the `ToolbarController` to be in the root area of the `NavigationDrawerController`, you only need to do this:

```
NavigationDrawerController(rootViewController: AppToolbarController(rootViewController: RootViewController))
```

You can continue this pattern with any controller that has a `rootViewController` initializer.